# Stop Blender from exporting the additional Armature root bone/object in FBX files

Tags: animation, rigging, export, unity, .fbx

I am having a problem when trying to export my animation to Unity. What happens is that whenever I export the .FBX file, Blender adds an extra object named "Armature". Therefore, the hierarchy of the object is:

> Root > Armature > Hips > Spine, RightLeg, LeftLeg

This would be fine, but I have other animations in Unity that use the Mixamo rig. I am editing those animations from Mixamo in Blender, but when I export them the Armature object is added, therefore it is mismatching the actual rig from Mixamo and therefore I cannot use it.
This is the rig hierarchy from Mixamo, to make it clear:

> Root > Hips > Spine, RightLeg, LeftLeg

I have tried multiple things in order to fix this, such as deleting the `Hips` parent and renaming `Armature` to `Hips`, however this causes rotational problems and also disconnects the legs from the spine as the Armature object is not the bone.

I have also tried intercepting the import process in Unity by using `AssetPostprocessor.OnPostprocessModel` and removing the `Armature` object automatically from Unity, but that did not work for some reason.

What would be my best approach to solving this?

*Note: The `Armature` object does not show up in Unity when the rig is set to `Generic`, only when it is set to `Humanoid` (which is what I need)*

Comment: did you try to apply armature first ? I mean before exporting it ? or else you may try in FBX exporting dialog to check "only selected" (referring to your mesh ofc)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by applying armature (I'm quite new to blender), but I tried exporting only the selection (the rig, without selecting the armature) and the armature was still exported as an additional root bone

Comment: The armature is typically a modifier, so you can "apply" it as you do with the rest of the modifiers. Although, why is it a problem to export it with your mesh ? If you don't need a bone system and you want only the vertex animations consider to use alembic instead :)

Comment: Name the armature Mixamo and it will work with mixamo animations... not sure why this works but it did for my tests.

Comment: How you find any solution?